# want to remove line ' _name, status from gv$instance;' from file with sed solaris

Tags: unix

sending mail to Admin
_name, status from gv$instance;
INSTANCE_NAME    HOST_NAME                                                        STATUS

---

Comment: Is there a question here? Have you tried anything? `sed`, perhaps?

Comment: my question is how can i use sed command to delete a line in a file and the line is: _name, status from gv$instance; INSTANCE_NAME

Answer (score 0):

I found out i nneded to re0directory the output of the sed command to a new file. See below:
sed '/_name, status from gv$instance;/d' /home/sedward/Prod_env_health.log > /home/sedward/1_Prod_env_health.log